# Getting url path from ASP.net MVC route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
public class PageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Render(string url)
    {
        //this is just for testing!
        return Content("url was " + url);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass in the value of the url into the controller.   For example:
http://www.site.com/products/something/else

Would pass "products/something/else" into my Render action of the PageController.

This is because we are using "products/something/else" as a unique key for a record in the database (legacy system, don't ask)

So, my resultant query would be something along the lines of this:

```
select * from foo where urlKey = 'products/something/else'
```

So far I have this in my RegisterRoutes section on Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute("pages", "{*url}", new { controller = "Page", action = "Render", url="/" });
```

But this isn't working as expected...

By visiting www.site.com/products/something/else, the value passed into the controller is "home/index/0"
The only route defined in RegisterRoutes is that described in the question.

Comment: What isn't working as expected? What is expected? What is the actual result?

Comment: Edited to answer your questions

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you are describing. I have created a new ASP.NET MVC application, defined the PageController exactly as shown in your question, the RegisterRoutes exactly as shown in your question and when I hit F5, I see: `url was products/something/else`. Could you please provide detailed instructions on how we could reproduce your problem?

Comment: The route works for me too.. I would have checked before answering the question :(

Comment: @DarinDimitrov @Mark For me, it spits out `url was home/index/0`

Comment: @alexjamesbrown, in this case you will have to provide a detailed instruction on how to reproduce this because you seem to be the only one encountering this problem. We cannot reproduce the issue you are explaining, the code works. So we cannot tell you why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below class matches every route but you can modify as per your needs.

```
public class LegacyRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
      RouteData result = null;

      string url = httpContext.Request.RawUrl.Substring(1);

      result = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
      result.Values.Add("controller", "Page");
      result.Values.Add("action", "Render");
      result.Values.Add("url", url);

      return result;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
      return null;
    }
}
```

In Global.asax.cs

```
routes.Add(new LegacyRoute());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, one of our routes does something similar and this is the code:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Standard",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, action = ControllersAndActions.TypicalController.IndexAction, page = 1 },
            constraints: new
            {
                controller = ControllersAndActions.ControllerConstraintExpression
            }
        );
```